# How to merge forked repo into main repo with conflicts?

Tags: git, github

I have one scenario where in my Project I have a main repository and I forked it and did some changes (around 40 commits in 15 files). Now I would like to merge these changes into the main repository. I made a PULL request to the main branch but there are lot of conflicts to resolve first. I followed some options from web to resolve but couldn't figure out the right solution.

I simulated the same scenario with local projects. The main repository is https://github.com/guntukaramakrishna/UtilsJava

And forked repository is https://github.com/rksatniit/UtilsJava.

The main has one change in one file and added with new file. And the forked repo has been made with some changes in two files. This is all I have to simulate the same scenario.

Could you please help me out with the right steps ?

Thanks and Regards 
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

1. You can `git fetch origin` from remote main repository. Then `git checkout branch`, merge main repository in local branch, `git rebase origin master`
2. In case of conflict, git rebase will stop at the first problematic commit and leave conflict markers in the tree. You need to resolve the conflict.
3. Then you `git add filename`.
4. After resolving the conflict, you can continue the rebasing process with `git rebase --continue`.[git rebase command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
5. Push local branch to remote, update pull request, `git push --force origin branch`
6. Now, you can merge your branch

Answer (score 0):

You have several options;

1) Let the recipient of your pull request resolve the conflicts when they pull/merge it.

2 You can merge the original repo into your fork and resolve the conflicts during the merge. Then the original can pull in your merge without conflicts (because you resolved them).

3) you can rebase your fork on top of the original repo and resolve the conflicts during the rebase. Then send a new oull request that will merge cleanly.

Note that `1` and `2` preserves the repository history, while `3` rewrites it.